# App Crashes-No Return From Webservice

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, google-maps, crash

So i have developed this app that accesses the google maps on the device. after that it reads the corner cordinates (top left and bottom right) of the screen visible on the device and stores the values in variables xmin xmax ymin and ymax. now these values are passed to the web service,

```
http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral_1_1.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2
```

along with other parameter as mentioned in the code to get the cordinates of the annotations that need to be plotted in that area.

now for the values hard coded values such as,

```
 xmin= -100
    ymin= -99
    xmax= 40
    ymax= 41
```

the program works fine, the output is an xml that is parsed and annotations are plotted but when i try to use the corner cordinates as visible on the map, the values being,

```
40338927
-99388178
40347297
-99399164
```

there is no return from the web service. this makes the app crash. i dont want it to crash but plot nothing which will denote that there is no station within that region. How can i do that.

Please Help,

thanx in advance

the code:

AndroidTestActivity.java

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends MapActivity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ArrayList<String> arrlat_long = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arrlat_lat = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
private static final String ACTION_RECV_MSG = "com.imrankhanandroid.intent.action.RECEIVE_MESSAGE";  
private static final String ACTION_OTHER_MSG = "com.imrankhanandroid.intent.action.OTHER_MESSAGE"; 
MapView mapView;
private MessageReceiver receiver ; 
private MapController mapController;
double topLat;
double topLon;
double bottomLat;
double bottomLon;
String strtest,strtest1,strtest2,strtest3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(8);


    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();  
    GeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);
    GeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth()-1, mapView.getHeight()-1);
    topLat = topLeft.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
    topLon = topLeft.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
    bottomLat = bottomRight.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
    bottomLon = bottomRight.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
    int n= ((int) (topLat*1E6));

    int n1= ((int) (topLon*1E6));

    int n2= ((int) (bottomLat*1E6));

    int n3= ((int) (bottomLon*1E6));

    strtest=Integer.toString(n)+"/"+Integer.toString(n1)+"/"+Integer.toString(n2)+"/"+Integer.toString(n3);
    Log.d("strtest strtest", "strtest strtest = "+strtest);
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(AndroidTestActivity.this,Intentservice.class); 
    msgIntent.putExtra("strtest", strtest);  //arrlat_long
    startService(msgIntent); 




    //Dynamic registration Receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RECV_MSG);  
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);  
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(ACTION_OTHER_MSG);  
    filter2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter2);  
}  
  //Broadcast to receive 
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
        arrlat_long = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("codnt");  
        arrlat_lat = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("codntlat");  
      // text.setText(message);      
    Toast.makeText(context, arrlat_long.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    testoverlay();
    }  
}  
public void testoverlay()
{
   for(int i=0;i<arrlat_long.size();i++)
   {

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapmarker);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
        float lat = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_lat.get(i));
        float lng = Float.parseFloat(arrlat_long.get(i));
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

   }

}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

HelloItemizedOverlay.java

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 private Context mContext;

 public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
 {
 super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
 mContext = context;
 }

 public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
 {
 mOverlays.add(overlay);
 populate();
 }
 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
 {
 return mOverlays.get(i);
 }
 @Override
 public int size()
 {
 return mOverlays.size();
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean onTap(int index)
 {

 return true;
 }
}
```

IntentService.java

```
public class Intentservice extends IntentService 
{
private static final String ACTION_RECV_MSG = "com.imrankhanandroid.intent.action.RECEIVE_MESSAGE";
private static final String ACTION_OTHER_MSG = "com.imrankhanandroid.intent.action.OTHER_MESSAGE"; 
ArrayList<String> arrlat_long = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arrlat_lat = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String str="";
public static String str1="";
int n=0;
String responseBody;
Integer topLat=0;
Integer topLon=0;
Integer bottomLat=0;
Integer bottomLon=0;
ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> b= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> c= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> d= new ArrayList<String>();
MapView mapView;
private MessageReceiver receiver;


public Intentservice()
{
    super("Intentservice");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    String strxmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;
    String str=intent.getExtras().getString("strtest");
    Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent onHandleIntent= "+str);
    String[] arrtelog=str.split("/");
    strxmin=arrtelog[0];
    xmax=arrtelog[1];
    ymin=arrtelog[2];
    ymax=arrtelog[3];

   // strxmin=str;
  //  xmax=str1;
  //  ymin=str2;
  //  ymax=str3;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
     String Url = "http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral_1_1.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2";
     if(!Url.endsWith("?"))
     {
            Url += "?";
     }

     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);   
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmin",xmax));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmax", ymax));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymin", "40"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymax", "41"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("networkIDs", ""));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("conceptKeyword", "precipitation"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beginDate", "1/1/2009"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", "1/1/2010"));
     String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
     Url += paramString;
     try 
        {
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url); 
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
           XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
           factory.setValidating(false);
           XmlPullParser myxml = factory.newPullParser();
           InputStream raw = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes());
           myxml.setInput(raw, null);
           int eventType = myxml.getEventType();

           while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
           {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) 
             {

                 Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start document");
             }
             else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
             {
                 if (myxml.getName().equals("latitude"))
                    {
                        str="";
                        str  =  myxml.nextText().toString();
                         Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start tag = "+str);
                         arrlat_lat.add(str);
                    }
                    if (myxml.getName().equals("longitude"))
                    {
                        str = myxml.nextText().toString();
                         Log.d("ParseXmlActivity", "In start tag = "+str);
                         arrlat_long.add(str);
                    }

           }

           eventType = myxml.next();

   } }
   catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
   {
   } 
   catch (IOException e)
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RECV_MSG); 
     filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
     receiver = new MessageReceiver();  
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter); 



   Log.d("TEST TESTTEST", "In start TESTTEST = "+arrlat_long.get(0)+" $$$ "+arrlat_long.size());
   Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();  
   broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_RECV_MSG);  
   broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
   broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codnt", arrlat_long);  //arrlat_long
   broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codntlat", arrlat_lat);  //arrlat_lat
   sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);  
}
```

the log cat is,

```
    06-29 18:37:18.786: W/dalvikvm(1344): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Intentservice]
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.Intentservice.onHandleIntent(Intentservice.java:157)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-29 18:37:19.086: D/dalvikvm(1344): GC_CONCURRENT freed 168K, 3% free 10132K/10375K, paused 4ms+4ms
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344): Activity com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity$MessageReceiver@412bf4a0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity$MessageReceiver@412bf4a0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1043)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1030)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1024)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestActivity.java:81)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-29 18:37:20.527: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344): Activity com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity$MessageReceiver@412d2f88 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity$MessageReceiver@412d2f88 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1043)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1030)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1024)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.AndroidTestActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestActivity.java:85)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-29 18:37:20.557: E/ActivityThread(1344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: posted !! would be really thankful if you could help

Comment: what the code on Intentservice.java:157 ?? There is IndexOutOfBoundsException because your array has no item added and you are trying to access first item with 0 index

Comment: broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codnt", arrlat_long);  //arrlat_long

Comment: please put if(arrlat_long!=null) before that line and execute your project

Comment: done but dint help, same crash problem

 if(arrlat_long!=null)       broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("codnt", arrlat_long);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13234/discussion-between-android-coader-and-tanzeel-ahmed)

Comment: join this chat room for further discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13234/discussion-between-android-coader-and-tanzeel-ahmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as your logcat line:

```
at com.imrankhanandroid.Androidtest.Intentservice.onHandleIntent(Intentservice.java:157)
06-29 18:37:18.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
```

means problem is in onHandleIntent in IntentService:

```
Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    String strxmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;
    String str=intent.getExtras().getString("strtest");
    Log.d("onHandleIntent", "onHandleIntent onHandleIntent= "+str);
    String[] arrtelog=str.split("/");
   if(arrtelog.length >=3)
    {
      strxmin=arrtelog[0];
      xmax=arrtelog[1];
      ymin=arrtelog[2];
      ymax=arrtelog[3];
    }
  else{
     //your code here if array length is 0
   }
```

Comment: This is right, I accidentally selected the wrong piece of code to correct although it is the same concept in my post.  This should be an immediate fix to the OP's question.

Comment: @Atlos :Thanks,if you agree with my answer then upvote it and @ Tanzeel try it i'm sure this will solve yor issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception then you are doing exactly that.  If your `ArrayList` size is 0, then calling `<yourlist>.get(0)` will crash because there is no 0th item in the list.  To fix this just check the `ArrayList` to see if it is null or empty like:

```
if(arrlat_long != null && arrlat_long.isEmpty() == false)
    Toast.makeText(context, arrlat_long.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or you could use a `try/catch` and catch the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception and choose to ignore it since you seem to expect this.